# Creating a weird type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

How can I create a type that will represent the objects like the one below in TypeScript?

```
const definition = {
    'with_boolean_prop': {
        prop1: true
    },
    'with_object_prop': {
        prop2: {
            options: {}
        }
    }
    'with_multiple_props': {
        prop3: {
            options: {}
        }
        prop4: true
    }
};
```

Keys will be strings as in `{ [key: string]: any }`. Anything can be used for the names prop1 and prop2. But their types must be `boolean` or an interface that only includes an `options` property.

This is what I have so far:

```
type ItemSchema = { options: string };
type Item = { [key: string]: Boolean | ItemSchema };
type Schema = { [key: string]: Item };

const schema: Schema = {
    'item1': {
        'prop1': true,
        'prop2': {
            options: 'some options'
        }
    }
};
```

Works but I can only use strings for the prop names, as the indexers in TypeScript can only be strings or numbers which is kind of limiting.

**EDIT**
There's been some misunderstanding, probably because of my English :-) I'm not against using strings or numbers for indexers. What I'm trying to achieve is define a type whose properties can only be a set of predefined types.

Like this:

```
myObject = {
    aProperty: Can be Boolean | Object
    bProperty: Can be Boolean | Object
    xxxProperty: Can be Boolean | Object
    anyProperty: Can be Boolean | Object
}
```

If I use string indexers for the property names, than I can achieve what I want as you can see from the example above (ItemSchema and other types) because it's possible to use any value in a string indexer. If I try to do this without string keys, than I can't restrict the types that the property can accept.

Comment: Yeah, -1 right away :-)

Comment: Can't you simply use `const schema: Schema = {
    item1: {
        prop1: true,
        prop2: {
            options: 'some options'
        }
    }
};` without the quotes in property name? It seems that works to. Also I think restriction of only string or number for property name is quite justified. :)

Comment: No, because I don't know the name of the properties in advance.

Comment: Then consider including a sample usage of `Schema`

Comment: Please give an example of js object where the indexer type, `string` or ` number`, is a limitation for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your current solution is not far from what you're trying to achieve. If I understood correctly, the problem is that you would like to also use `number` as prop name instead of only `string`, right ?

If yes, then you can use `&` to create an Intersection type. Here's your example implementing this :

```
type ItemSchema = { options: string };
type Item = { [key: string]: Boolean | ItemSchema } & { [key: number]: Boolean | ItemSchema };
type Schema = { [key: string]: Item };

const schema: Schema = {
    'item1': {
        'prop1': true,
        'prop2': {
            options: 'some options'
        },
        4: true,
        5: {
            options: 'an other option'
        },
    }
};
```

Here is the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20definition%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20'with_boolean_prop'%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20prop1%3A%20true%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20'with_object_prop'%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20prop2%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20options%3A%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20'with_multiple_props'%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20prop3%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20options%3A%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20prop4%3A%20true%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ItemSchema%20%3D%20%7B%20options%3A%20string%20%7D%3B%0D%0Atype%20Item%20%3D%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20Boolean%20%7C%20ItemSchema%20%7D%20%26%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20number%5D%3A%20Boolean%20%7C%20ItemSchema%20%7D%3B%0D%0Atype%20Schema%20%3D%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20Item%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20schema%3A%20Schema%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20'item1'%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'prop1'%3A%20true%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'prop2'%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20options%3A%20'some%20options'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%204%3A%20true%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%205%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20options%3A%20'an%20other%20option'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B) of the code.